# Inverse matching with exiftool

Tags: bash, exiftool

I am sorting pictures based on the contents in the `subject` pseudo tag of `exiftool`, which generally look something like this:

`15: D101-5-12 1: Elephas maximus 16: Bob`

Usually I sort the images based on the species name in the second line, however, for some images the second line is missing and I would like to filter these images out.

The first and third line vary a lot between pictures, so I am unable to utilise these. Instead, I have been trying various 'inverse matching' methods suggested on other questions surrounding this topic, but with no success. For example, the following does not work:

```
exiftool -r -if '\$subject=~/^((?!1:\s).)*$/i' \
'-Filename=./image_sorted/%f%+c%E' image_directory
```

Any ideas on how to do this with `exiftool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I realize that all your species keywords start with `1:`, I think I can make a better, all in one command for you.

`exiftool -r '-Filename=./image_sorted/%f%+c%E' '-Filename<./${Subject;$_=undef if not s/.*(?:^|, )1: (.*?)(,|$).*/$1/}/%f%+c%E' ./image_directory/`

This command will move any file that doesn't have a keyword that starts with `1:` into the `image_sorted` directory.  If it does have a keyword that starts with `1:`, it will move it into a directory based upon the species name and this will override the previous option to move it into the `image_sorted` directory.

This command will throw a `Warning: [minor] Tag 'Subject' not defined` and a `Warning: No writable tags set` warning for any file that doesn't have the `1: Species Name` keyword set.  These can be safely ignored and you can avoid them completely by adding the `-m` option.

Comment: Technically, this doesn't answer *this* question but I think it better reaches your original goal.

Comment: First of all, this is brilliant! Thank you very much. Secondly, are `<` and `=` interchangeable in `exiftool`? And lastly, I believe you are missing the source directory at the end.

Comment: No, the `<`/`>` and `=` signs are not interchangeable.  This is [common mistake #5c](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M5) and one I had a lot of problems with and still occasionally mess up on. 

The equal sign `=` is used to assign a static value to a tag.  The greater/less than signs `<`/`>` are used to copy a tag to another tag.  You can add static data when copying a tag, but you can't copy a tag with the equal sign.

Yeah, left the directory off because I was being lazy, I'll add it in.

Make sure and test the command, but it should work ok for you.

Comment: To address the problem of your regex, it matches zero or more occurrences of `1: ` followed by one more of any other character.  So it would match `1: a1: b1: c` etc.  Also, you required the match to be at the start of the line, but `$subject` is a string combining all of the keywords and there's no telling what order they may be in.  A more proper match would have been `-if '$Subject!~/(?:^|, )1: .*?(?:, |$)`

Comment: One final warning, if the Species Name has a comma in it, then the command will only grab the part of the name before the comma.  If this is the case, it is possible to change things around to accommodate it.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful explanations! I have unfortunately come across a problem when attempting to store the images without a species into a subdirectory. It might be better to formulate another question, but `-Filename=../Data/image_sorted/Empty/%f%+c%E` doesn't store the picture in the `Empty` directory, but in the `image_sorted` directory. Any ideas?

Comment: It shouldn't unless there's something in the data that I'm missing.  Maybe bring the issue over to the [exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/) where you can post more details and maybe an example image?  Also, it gets a few more eyes on the problem.